# java setText is not working in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Trying to display sql results in a JLabel. I'm using netbeans so it does auto code generation for the swing components.

Welcome_screen.java, main method

```
package my.welcomescreen;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Welcome_screen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  public Welcome_screen() {
    initComponents();

  }

  private void initComponents() {

    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Welcome_screen courses = new Welcome_screen();
    courses.getCourses();


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Welcome_screen().setVisible(true);

         }
      });
   }

  public void getCourses(){

    db obj = new db();
    obj.dbconnect();
    String Query = "select * from courses";
    try{
        Connection con = obj.dbconnect();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

        if(rs.next()){
            //System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
            jLabel9.setText(rs.getString("name"));
        }



    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}

private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;

}
```

db.java, database connect file.

```
package my.welcomescreen;
import java.sql.*;

public class db {

    public static Connection dbconnect(){
        Connection con=null;
         try {

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/st2", "root", "");


    }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
      System.out.println(e);
  }
     return con; 
 }

}
```

when i print sql results to the command line it works. expected result is displaying. But in the JLabel nothing happens. Not even an error is occurring. I can't find what's wrong. A little help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

At first: YOU HAVE TO PLACE THE JLABEL on the Frame:

```
getContentpane().add(label9);
```

And after on i recommend to take a look at the following Methods:

```
rame.setSize(width, height);
Frame.getContentPane();
Container/JComponent.add(Component c);
Component.setLayout(LayountManager manager);
```

I recommend to watch more vids or read Blogs about Swing bevore continuing. But here is the code u should use:

```
private void initComponents() {

    label9 = new JLabel();
    label9.setText("SOME TEXT");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setSize(100, 50);
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.add(jLabel9);
    p.setVisible(true);

    setSize(200, 200);
    getContentPane().add(p);

}
```

Try to call

```
jlabel9.setText("Your readen text!");
jlabel9.repaint();
```

It will repaint the label and update the content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate `jLabel9` on the jPanel and it on `Frame`. One of the way is to use a constructor. As your class is exended from JFrame, you don't need to use `this.add()` or `JFrame jf = new JFrame();`

```
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9.setBackground(Color.red);
    jLabel9.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setText("Hello");
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setSize(100, 50);
    jp.add(jLabel9);
    jp.setVisible(true);

    setSize(200, 200);
    add(jp);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

or directly on `JFrame`

```
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9.setBackground(Color.red);
    jLabel9.setVisible(true);
    jLabel9.setText("Hello");
        setSize(200, 200);
        add(jLabel9);
// one of other way to use contentpane
// getContantPane().add(jLabel9);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the 1st method and it's just flashes the sql result.

Comment: I cannot see it because I don't have the installed db, but I am going to check it

Comment: Try to remark this line: jLabel9.setText("Hello"); and it won't blick, I think

Answer (score 0):

Please try this like -

```
jlabel.setText("Your Text");
jLabel.setVisisble(true);
```